# Why aren't search engines showing my site anymore?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, web-crawlers, search

I have created a site as a home project but for some reason, it stopped showing my site in Google. I connected my site to Google Search Console and most of the pages are indexed. At least I can see it in Google Search Console and via adding `site://` prefix in Google.

As you can see the problem is not in CTR. My site gets ~0 impressions which means google does not show it at all - [image]

What can be a problem?